# jQuery Mobile hover side panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use jQuery Mobile for desktop. I am building a social networking service and I want to use a left and right panel for each groups and message usage.

What I want is the side panel to appear when I hover over it's respective header bar button, like the sidebar in Google+.

Here is my code:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/openhiun/6gKjk/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <!--jqm cdn-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">
<!--groups panel-->
<div data-role="panel" id="groups-panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
LPS
</div>
<!--friends panel-->
<div data-role="panel" id="friends-panel" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">
LPS
</div>

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#groups-panel" id="groups-button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext">Groups</a>
        <h1>My Title</h1>
        <a href="#friends-panel" id="friends-button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext">Friends</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   

    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

How can I do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tip: that's not how you set up a fiddle, in the HTML section you should only put the `<body>` contents, scripts can be added via the "Frameworks & Extensions" or "External Resources" options on the left panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this code to your page

```
$('#groups-panel').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).panel("close");
});

$("#groups-button").hover(function () {
    $('#groups-panel').panel("open");
});

$('#friends-panel').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).panel("close");
});

$("#friends-button").hover(function () {
    $('#groups-panel').panel("open");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gKjk/1/)

Comment: it's exactly what i want! thank you! 
how can i learn jQuery Mobile Javascript API like you? if you know great instruction for it, please recommend some!